# Ajax misteriously stopped working on my entire website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a strangest problem with my website. After 2 full days of trying to sort it out, I still haven't managed to find what's wrong.

I recently noticed (I think it started after changing servers) that my `ajax` code is not working properly anymore. Before it was working like a charm. Here's an example of a login script from my online community:

Follows the form:

```
<form class="registration-form" name="signupform" onsubmit="return false;"> 
     <input type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Email"   id="email" autofocus>
     <input type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Password" id="password">
     <button type="submit" id="loginbtn" onclick="login()" >Log in!</button>
     <div id="status"></div>
</form>
```

Follows the JS:

```
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = 'Please fill out all the form data.';
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'Loading...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "login_failed"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = 'Login unscuccessful';
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "xxxx";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

Follows the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $e = strtolower($e);
    $p = md5($_POST['p']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        echo "login_failed";
        exit();
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            echo "login_failed";
            exit();
        } else {
            //set cookies and log user in
        }
    }
    exit();
}
```

Although the `php` of the form is working and when all values are correct the user is logged in, the `ajax` is not showing any status or loading message like it should with the code above.

Nothing else changed with the scripts. I still include `ajax.js` and `jquery` at the top of the page like before.

This is just one example. The form I use to let people register is the same as this one and has the same problem, just like any other `ajax` form on my website.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Any clue from the Console?

Comment: If you open the JavaScript console in Chrome (press F12), do you see any errors when rendering the page ? A small syntax error in your JS can stop it from working all together.

Comment: Check the console, you might find something out there.

Comment: `JavaScript console in Chrome` - or any other browser at all

Comment: is this jquery or underscore?

Comment: check your network see whats the result in your ajax

Comment: Did you happen to change from http to https as well

Comment: I checked my console but no errors... I did not change from http to https, it has always been https. In the network tab it says Ajax status 200 OK

Comment: @NewbeeDev when I echo the status, I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better use json when getting data from server to javascript (AJAX)

```
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $e = strtolower($e);
    $p = md5($_POST['p']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

    $json['success'] = true;

    if($e == "" || $p == ""){
        $json['success'] = false;
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx,"SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email='$e' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $db_id = $row[0];
        $db_username = $row[1];
        $db_pass_str = $row[2];
        if($p != $db_pass_str){
            $json['success'] = false;
        } else {
            //set cookies and log user in
        }
    }
    // display your return data as json
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

wrap the inside of your onreadystatechange function to

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

}
```

remove your condition which is

```
if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
}
```

your js file is now like this

```
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function login(){
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p = _("password").value;
    if(e == "" || p == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = 'Please fill out all the form data.';
    } else {
        _("loginbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'Loading...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "login.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            // when ajax is now okay and request finished and response is ready
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                // debugging purpose display response
                console.log(result);

                if(result.success == true){
                    _("status").innerHTML = 'Login unscuccessful';
                    _("loginbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.location = "xxxx";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e+"&p="+p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error in the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: try console.log(this.responseText); let me see whats the result

Comment: when I replace console.log(result) with console.log(this.responseText), I get the same uncought syntaxerror

Comment: put the console.log(this.responseText); return; before var result = JSON.parse(this.innerHTML);

Comment: My console now logs an empty row followed by the same error

Comment: screen shot your php code

Comment: Ahw the mistake here is var result = JSON.parse(this.innerHTML); should be var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

Comment: ahahah I forgot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125097/discussion-between-senne-vandenputte-and-newbee-dev).